# bash: replace . with \. in a variable

Tags: regex, bash, sed, environment-variables

Below is my questions

```
RELEASE_BRANCH=5.2.2

echo $RELEASE_BRANCH | sed 's/\./\\./g'
5\.2\.2

RELEASE=`echo $RELEASE_BRANCH|sed 's/\./\\./g'`

echo $RELEASE
5.2.2
```

What I am expecting

```
echo $RELEASE
5\.2\.2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried sed `'s/\./\\\\./g'`?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to "accept" an answer once you've gotten one you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of [back-ticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) is deprecated. You should use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

RELEASE_BRANCH=5.2.2
RELEASE=$(echo $RELEASE_BRANCH|sed 's/\./\\./g')

echo "$RELEASE"
```

**Note:** Please read the Important differences (bullet 1) from the [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, then this should give you your expected result -

```
$ RELEASE=$(echo $RELEASE_BRANCH|sed 's/\./\\./g')
$ echo $RELEASE
5\.2\.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using backticks, you need to escape the backslashes one extra time:

```
RELEASE=`echo $RELEASE_BRANCH|sed 's/\\./\\\\./g'`
```

Answer (score 1):

You also use this method,

```
$RELEASE=`echo $RELEASE_BRANCH|sed -r 's/\./\\\&/g'`
$echo $RELEASE
 5\.2\.2
```

Answer (score 1):

We seldom think about the powerful string-manipulation functions made available by **bash**, and in this case the following works very well:

> ${string/substring/replacement}
>
> ```
> Replace first match of $substring with $replacement.
> ```
>
> ${string//substring/replacement}
>
> ```
> Replace all matches of $substring with $replacement.
> ```

So here we are going to use the second version, to have a neat one-liner:

```
$ RELEASE_BRANCH=5.2.2
$ echo ${RELEASE_BRANCH//./\\.}
5\.2\.2
```